# Repeater live update

Tags: c#, repeater, live

How would you "live update" a repeater control in .NET?

It could be a chat fx, where entries would come from an SQL database. So whenever someone writes into the textfield and hit the submit button, the text would instantly show on the page, which is a repeater control showing content from the SQL table.

Comment: [SignalR](http://signalr.net/) is your friend

Comment: Wow fast reply there! ;) Thanks, i'll have a look a that

Comment: SignalR is a part of the friendship...